# Pairing Bluetooth with a Zebra Printer without user pairing confirmation

Tags: android, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I'm working on a small project and I need to pair by Nexus 7 (android v4.2.1) with a Zebra Printer. I'm using the Bluetooth API of android and I call createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid) to get a Bluetooth socket, but when I call connect() on this socket I still getting the user pairing confirmation. I dig a lot in this forum to get a solution but I can't get on working solution... If someone can help me I appreciate a lot!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zebra provides an Android API to handle all the connection communications (including Bluetooth).  Go [download the API](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-android.html) and check out `BluetoothPrinterConnection`

Comment: I'm currently using the ZDK to android and I'm still getting the pairing request each time I connect via bluetooth.

Comment: What kind of printer are you using? If you want to use the SDK, it requires a pin and then Android pops up that dialog.  If you want to do the insecure connection on your own, you need to turn off authentication on the printer and then you should be OK

Comment: I found now the problem... the problem is the android version on the device that I'm testing.... I tested with a android v4.2.1 device and I still getting the pairing request, but when I use an android device 2.3.6 and another v3.1 it works fine!I guess its a misleading of version 4 of android SDK....